# Optimized recommendations engine in ArangoDB

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I am testing now building a proof of concept for a recommendation engine based on graphs. I need to optimize one query (test query), in order to compare response time with wished one.

Small part of graph:

[image: Products graph]

I want to make the following scenario: **Similar products**.
It should take products from same category and order them by visits of same customer (ex. if Customer1 visited Product1 and Product2, then they could be similar products). Query should count those common customers visits starting from one product and order by this score.

Ex. in graph above, for Product2, there are Product1 and Product3 from same category and Product1 has 1 visit from common user, Product3 has 2 visits, so recommendations will be: {Product3, Product1}.

How should I construct graph query using AQL in order to get good response time.